# Is there any special names for the straight lines on a curved surface?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, terminology

I am not sure whatever I am talking even makes any sense. I am thinking of a straight line on a curved surface. Actually the term 'straight' here means the line should move in same direction along the surface of the body. For simplicity you can imagine of a long straight wire and you bend it around a solid body without bending       it laterally. The resulting line of wire is the one I am talking about.

I have some questions about such line but at first I need to be sure that such a thing can be actually defined properly. My question is are such lines previously defined, if yes what are those lines called, if not can it be defined ?

[It can also be thought as an extended geodesic since geodesic is just the shortest line segment between two points.But I think of an infinitely long(may be closed-loop) line not just a segment.]

Comment: [Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that but I dont think geodesic is actually what I meant. Geodesic is the shortest path between two point. It is just a lines segment. But here I am talking of infinite or closed-loop line which I dont think is geodesic.

Comment: The term "geodesic" applies to both the shortest path between two points and its infinitely extended version, because there is usually not much point in distinguishing between the two. For example, see [closed geodesic](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Closed_geodesic).

Comment: It's not so much that you have "geodesics" between two points and "extended geodesics" that go on indefinitely (possibly looping). A "geodesic" can already be considered to go on indefinitely; a "geodesic *segment*" or "geodesic *arc*" stops at the endpoints, but people ofttimes don't bother to say "segment" or "arc". See, for instance, that [this question about geodesics on the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/703549/409) makes no mention of endpoints.

Comment: Then I think this answered my question.

Comment: This is truly confusing language, as there are lots of surfaces that contain plenty of true lines (i.e., a line in $\Bbb R^3$ that is wholly contained in the surface). This is a different notion from that of a geodesic in the surface, although every true line is obviously a geodesic.